# wordpress gives 503 error when huge menu added

Tags: wordpress, menu

approximately 350 menu items want to add into the website using Wordpress but it takes a long time and then gives 503 error.

```
PHP Version:    7.2.34
PHP Post Max Size:  64 MB
PHP Time Limit: 30
PHP Max Input Vars: 5000
SUHOSIN Installed:  –
Max Upload Size:    64 MB
```